# Using STRING_SPLIT to normalize data in temp tables?

Tags: sql, split, cross-apply

I have a use case where I need to create a table of values containing a bin location in a warehouse and the coordinate of that bin. My issue is the data is given to me in the following format:

```
(27,1) S,S,S
(1,34) F,F,F
```

I have an entire column of this data so my approach was to use STRING_SPLIT to separate the coordinate from the name.

```
INSERT INTO ##TestTemp
SELECT
s.CustomerID,
s1.[value] AS [BinInfo],
[RN] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID)
FROM ##TempTable s
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.[BinGrid], ' ') s1

SELECT * INTO ##CoordTemp
FROM ##TestTemp WHERE ([RN]%2)=1
SELECT * FROM ##CoordTemp

SELECT * INTO ##NameTemp
FROM ##TestTemp WHERE ([RN]%2)=0
SELECT * FROM ##NameTemp
```

My desired output is:

| BinCoord | BinNumb |
| --- | --- |
| (27,1) | S,S,S |
| (1,34) | F,F,F |

I have used STRING_SPLIT and a CROSS APPLY after which I separate by RN (even and odd) into 2 temp tables, which gets me close to the desired result (see below), however I am having trouble linking the bin number to its coordinate. Trying to reconnect the data is giving me issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

| BinCoord | RN |
| --- | --- |
| (27,1) | 1 |
| (1,34) | 3 |

| BinNumb | RN |
| --- | --- |
| S,S,S | 2 |
| F,F,F | 4 |

Comment: Only idea I have is to use an identity column before the split and then use that to rejoin but seems like there may be a better option, I am new to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking things.

Based on your sample data and a single split-point on the space, simply use Charindex:

```
 with sampledata as (select * from (values('(27,1) S,S,S'),('(1,34) F,F,F'))x(BinGrid))

select Left(BinGrid, p - 1) BinCoord, Stuff(BinGrid, 1, p, '') BinNumb
from sampledata d
cross apply(values(NullIf(CharIndex(' ', Bingrid), 0)))s(p);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, that is exactly what I need! I dont have enough rep to upvote, but I accepted your solution.

Comment: Do you know how I could then insert the result to a temp table? @Stu

Comment: `select .... into #mytable from sampledata...`

Comment: I get "Invalid object name 'sampledata'" when using this line underneath the code from your answer

Comment: Ugh, replace `sampledata` with your actual table name.